# Smart Links in Objective-C

Tags: html, objective-c, frameworks, hyperlink

I have an Objective-C application that uses WebKit for rendering and I would like a system to automatically detected the NSRanges of links and create them into the proper HTML anchor links. Currently I use a touchy regex to do this, but I am seeking a more sophisticated-like system that can tell the difference between links like http://wikipedia.org/test_(whatever) and that link being wrapped in parenthesis instead. Is there some de-facto framework I can use for Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHyperlinks](http://trac.adium.im/wiki/AutoHyperlinksFramework) does it well.